# difference between csymf and csym in prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am very confused what is the difference between csymf and csym in prolog, when I am using

```
?-code_type(X,csym).

X = 48 ;
X = 49 ;
....

?-code_type(X,csymf).

X = 65;
X = 66;
....
```

Would you please someone tell me what X should be exactly, I read the manual of SWI-prolog in this part and it is mentioned that

```
csym :Char is a letter (upper- or lowercase), digit or the underscore (_). These are valid C and Prolog symbol characters.

csymf :Char is a letter (upper- or lowercase) or the underscore (_). These are valid first characters for C and Prolog symbols.
```

So would you please provide me with some examples ?

Thanks

Comment: Use `char_type/2` and be aware that only Latin-1 characters are generated. Yet, `char_type/2` is defined for all Unicode characters. This is very SWI-specific.

Comment: ?-char_type(A,cymf). 
will give me all starting letters that can cymf type starts with, including letters capital and small,underscore, and also ?, and some latin letters.                                                       

?-  char_type(A,csym).
gives me all starting character for the csym including numbers, letters wether capital or small and also latin characters,

so I think that char_type(A,cymf),is a subset of char_type(A,cymf). 

Thanks for providing me such predicate to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have found the relevant descriptions, that state that code_type(Code, Type) holds a relation between a `character code` and his `classification`.

I think the manual is a bit misleading, because Prolog symbols are different than C (or Java, to say) symbols. These latter can be described with a regular expression like `[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*`, equivalent to the readable descriptions you cite.

Then `c9` is a valid C symbol, while `9c` is not (a digit cant start a symbol).

To inspect all 'properties' of a character (I assume you are aware of differences between character code - an integer - and the encoded character - localized), you could use

```
?- char_type(v,T).
T = alnum ;
T = alpha ;
T = csym ;
T = csymf ;
T = ascii ;
T = graph ;
T = lower ;
T = lower('V') ;
T = to_lower('V') ;
T = to_upper(v) ;
false.
```

Then `v` could start a `C symbol`.

```
?- char_type('7',T).
T = alnum ;
T = csym ;
T = ascii ;
T = digit ;
T = graph ;
T = to_lower('7') ;
T = to_upper('7') ;
T = digit(7) ;
T = xdigit(7).
```

We miss `csymf` here, then `7` cannot start a `C symbol`.

To get all the characters that can start a `C symbol`, you could use

```
?- forall(char_type(X,csymf),write(X)).
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzªµºÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ
true.
```

I think your result could be different than mine, depending on your locale.

Comment: It is not the locale that gives you this result. SWI's `char_type/2` is **not** a relation: `char_type('\x100\',csymf)` succeeds, yet `char_type(C,csymf), C = '\x100\'` fails. ``\x100\`` being `'Ā'` with appropriate locale.

Comment: @false: thanks for the clarification. My experience with non latin locales is void, and I can't find more details in SWI docs...

Comment: @false: sorry but I tried both of them and nothing is failed:

Comment: @false: sorry but I tried it, but it doesn't fail:

'code'
?- char_type('\x100\',csymf).

true.

?- char_type('\x100\',csym).
true.

I am using SWI-prolog

Comment: @false Ahaa, Sorry I misunderstand while I read it in the first time,
Thanks,